# indexOf() > -1 vs indexOf() != -1

Tags: javascript

I am reading Beginning JavaScript and in Chapter 10 there is this exercise:

```
 var myImages = [
        "usa.gif",
        "canada.gif",
        "jamaica.gif",
        "mexico.gif"
    ];

    function changeImg(e) {
        var el = e.target;
        var newImgNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);

        while (el.src.indexOf(myImages[newImgNumber]) != -1) {
            newImgNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
        }

        el.src = myImages[newImgNumber];
    }

    function updateStatus(e) {
        var el = e.target;
        var status = document.getElementById("status");

        status.innerHTML = "The image changed to " + el.src;

        if (el.src.indexOf("mexico") > -1) {
            el.removeEventListener("click", changeImg);
            el.removeEventListener("click", updateStatus);
        }
    }

    var imgObj = document.getElementById("img0");

    imgObj.addEventListener("click", changeImg);
    imgObj.addEventListener("click", updateStatus);
```

Why do they use `!= -1` here:

```
while (el.src.indexOf(myImages[newImgNumber]) != -1) {
```

and `> -1` here:

```
if (el.src.indexOf("mexico") > -1) {
```

the use of `-1` is confusing me.

Comment: Research what `Array.prototype.indexOf` does, and you will find your answer

Comment: The random element picker is seriously biased against picking the first and last element in the array.  Use `Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages.length)` instead.

Comment: This is an example from a book I do not understand why they use the > -1
I already looked at Array.prototype.indexOf but don't know why they use > -1 to see if the element was selected.

Comment: they use >-1 because is the result of indexof if the element is not present in the array....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indexOf returns a -1 if the search is not in the string. This is because indexOf will return the position of the search term in the string. For example

`> -1` is another way of saying `!== -1` though I personaly prefer the latter.

```
var test = 'testing';
test.indexOf('test'); // returns 0 which is falsy
test.indexOf('st'); // Returns 2
test.indexOf('foo'); // returns -1
```

Same goes for arrays.

Hope that helps answer why the -1!

Comment: So then > -1 or != -1 are two ways of saying that it definitely is in the variable?

Comment: I like to think of them as >-1 "found at any location" and !=-1 "not found". This is because I can always use the same phrase in my head if there is another important index. Say you are looking for something after the first 10 items (for whatever reason) then >10 means "found at any location after 10) and !=10 means "not found at 10". Logically the are interchangeable in your code, but I don't use them that way.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `-1` is because the `indexOf` operation will return `-1` in the event the searched for value does not exist in the array.

As for why they use `!= -1` in one place and `> -1` in another is probably an editor falling down on the job.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp):

"This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs."

The lines that you refer are conditions where if the element is actually in the array, then the condition is met.